# Why is apply not being applied

Tags: python, pandas

I have this initial dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'colX': ['TQ95','SM90','SJ07','SH97','TF28']})
```

So df is as follows:

```
    colX
0   TQ95
1   SM90
2   SJ07
3   SH97
4   TF28
```

No I create a very very simple function and apply it to df:

```
def foo(x):
    return x + 'bar'

df.apply(foo)
```

Returns:

```
    colX
0   TQ95bar
1   SM90bar
2   SJ07bar
3   SH97bar
4   TF28bar
```

So why does the following:

```
def bar(x):
    if len(x) == 4:
        return 'x'
    elif len(x) == 6:
        return 'y'
    else:
        return 'z'

df.apply(bar)
```

Return this?:

```
colX    z
dtype: object
```

Rather than this?:

```
    colX
0   x
1   x
2   x
3   x
4   x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
df['colX'].apply(bar)
```

Thus, only the length of the **column value** is checked.
The complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
def bar(x):
    if len(x) == 4:
        return 'x'
    elif len(x) == 6:
        return 'y'
    else:
        return 'z'

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'colX': ['TQ95','SM90','SJ07','SH97','TF28']})
df['colX'] = df['colX'].apply(bar)
```

Comment: this returns z rather than x - the length of the values e.g. TQ95 is 4 so why is this condition not true `if len(x) == 4:`?

Comment: @whytheq It returns x for me.

Comment: @whytheq: See the full code example in the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

`df.apply(foo)` is executed on every column of the DataFrame (for your case, only on `colX`). It is the same as `df['colX'] + 'bar'`. You are appending 'bar' to every string in that Series (`x` in that function is a Series so `x + 'bar'` is also a Series).

`df.apply(bar)` is also executed on that single column. It returns a scalar rather than a Series though. If you want it to be applied to every row, you need to pass `axis=1`:

```
df.apply(bar, axis=1)
Out: 
0    z
1    z
2    z
3    z
4    z
dtype: object
```

Comment: but why is it returning z rather than x ? each string in df is len of 4

Comment: Because x is a Series. For the default case, len(x) is the number of rows (number of elements in that Series) so it is equal to 5 therefore else is evaluated. If you want to check the lenght of the strings, use `df['colX'].str.len()`.

Comment: so do I need to use lamdda to apply this len to each individual value rather than the len of the series?

Comment: `lambda x: len(x['colX'])` is the correct way to check the lenght of the string in `colX`, assuming this is applied along axis=1.

Comment: basically I need to use bar against each value in colX without changing the function - is it possible so that I get a new column that is populated with x

Comment: Yes you can use @Jan's method. Since you are applying to a single Series, x will be evaluated as each element in that Series rather than each row/each column. This is the difference between `DataFrame.apply` and `Series.apply`.

Comment: thanks for this last comment - makes things a lot clearer.